# Swift variable giving wrong value

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a game in swift, I have a variable called `score`, I increment and print this variable in my `onTick()` method, and it works fine.  However when I try to access this variable to display the final score after the player dies, I get `0` or whatever the initial value was.

Initialization:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var score = 0;
```

Incrementing:

```
scoreCounter.text = String(self.score);
self.score += 1;
```

Trying to display it at endgame:

```
 print("SCORE: \(score)");
if (score > topScore) {
    endScore.textColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    endScore.text = "NEW HIGHSCORE! Score: " + String(score) + "   HighScore: " + String(topScore);
} else {
    endScore.text = "Score: " + String(score) + "   HighScore: " + String(topScore);
}
```

Any insight is appreciated! :)

Comment: If you have a global variable named `score` then creating a property inside your view controller with the same name will result in your view controller only editing it's own local property and not changing your global variable.

Comment: post more code.

Comment: @dan Sorry, I realize now it is not a global variable, my CS teacher told me it was and I was confused until I realized he was mistaken.

Comment: @random could you be more specific?

Comment: @Zacx is all of this code in the same class? are you pushing/popping view controllers?

Comment: @random yes I use this method to change my viewcontroller when the game starts, player dies, etc
http://pastebin.com/TK23UiYK

Comment: @Zacx post all of your code if you can. Specifically what's going on when "player dies"

Comment: @random this is the code executed when the player dies. http://pastebin.com/iwf2UhZw

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making the variable static, I don't know if this is the proper solution but it's working for me, thanks everyone for their help.`